# Machine Learning to check IBAN checksum

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am new in machine learning and I need some help and ideas.
I want to detect if an IBAN-Number is valid and it should be checked without the knowledge of the checksum algorithmn.

I want to train the AI with a lot of valid and invalid IBAN's.
After the training I want to test a IBAN and the system should tell me if it's a valid number.

I have a CSV-File with the following format...

IBAN,Valid
DE03683515573047232594,true
DE89500502010000180802,true
DE33100500000000484848,false
DE47701500000034343434,false
...

I am using Python 3.6 with numpy and sklearn.

```
#! python
import sys
import csv

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import numpy
import seaborn
import sklearn

filename    = "iban.csv"
raw_data    = open(filename, "rt")
reader      = csv.reader(raw_data)

iban_list   = list(reader)
data        = []

i = 0
for val in  numpy.array(iban_list):
    if i > 0:
        data.append(val)
    i += 1

from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Train Data
# https://www.ritchieng.com/pandas-scikit-learn/
# https://github.com/datacamp/courses-kaggle-python-machine-learning/blob/master/chapter2.md

train = pandas.read_csv(filename)
train.head()

feature_cols = ['IBAN', 'Valid']

# here I need some help =)
```

Regards
Ronny

Comment: Why would you try to build a system like this if the checksum calculation is known to be mod-97-10? A quick google search reveals this to be-> step 1: append two zeroes to occupy the check character positions: 79400;
step 2: divide by 97, to give the quotient 818 and the integer remainder 54;
step 3: determine the check character value as (97 + 1) - 54 = 44 and append it to the original string to give 79444.

Comment: Thats exaclty the reason because I wrote 
"it should be checked without the knowledge of the checksum algorithmn."
I want to solve it by machine learning.

Comment: Sure, you could do that but the accuracy is at best still lower than using the actual algorithm. That just made me curious as to why you would want to do that while there are endless useful things to be done with machine learning ... oO

Comment: It is only for learning purposes. Later, I want to adapt this to other things. I don't want to start with image classifaction or something like this.

I want to start with a simple thing like IBAN checksum.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: How can I validate a IBAN-Number without knowledge of the checksum-algorithmn with AI? 
Like I said before, I am new to machine learning and AI-Stuff and I want to know how to solve this with python and sklearn.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main point in this problem is to build a good feature vector. Assuming we don't know how IBAN numbers are validated, thus, we don't want that part of it is a checksum etc. I would build a feature vector with at least the following features:

1. The first two characters
2. Character 3-4
3. Character 5-8
4. Character 9-12
5. Character 9-End
6. The last two characters
7. The sum of all numbers
8. Maybe: The sum of all numbers mod different numbers

Then it is dependent how much training data you have. After preparing your data, you will give it to a classifier. I would try different classifiers like CNN and Decision Trees.
After training and you try to optimize the hyperparameters by your validation set.
Then you test it on the test data and compute the accuracy, f1-score...
It would be interesting to see how well this features behave and maybe you can add other features to optimize your classifier.
Then you can

Comment: It sounds nice. Do you have any sample code to do something like that? Regards Ronny

Comment: @RonnyCSHARP No. I don't have but maybe we can do it together if you are not in hurry. Because I have also other things to do.